# How do I rank rank values from a very large csv excel file when I only need a few data points from the file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I uploaded an incredibly large Excel file as such

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\willi\\Downloads\\Formatted Corona Virus Data.csv")

index = ['ARG', 'BOL', 'CHL', 'COL', 'CRI', 'CUB', 'ECU', 'PAN', 'PER', 'PRY']
```

and it looks like the image below obviously it continues on to more countries

how do I create a list to compare and rank these 10 countries from the index for total cases from the most recent date from most to least?

*edit some of them may have different most recent dates

[image]

Comment: what does your desirable output look like? A list of top counties by date?

Comment: FYI: you can use `r` for raw for windows paths (e.g. `pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\willi\Downloads\Formatted Corona Virus Data.csv")`) so you don't have to manually add `\\`

Answer (score 0):

How about

`df[df.iso_code.isin(index)].groupby(['index','date']).total_cases.rank()`?